# Struct of array global scope

Tags: c++, struct, scope, hashmap

I need a struct of array[lenght] to be seen by all my methods(global).

The problem I have is that the struct needs to be initialized with a specific length inside a specific function. To be more precise the initialization of struct with the length of size has to happen when importantFunction() is called and I need all my other fcts to have access to the struct.

This is the solution Ive come with. Im unaware of any other way to make the struct global.

***Cant use the hashMap or vector class***. This template is part of my own vector class.

```
template<class A>
class Table {
public:

    struct hash {
        T value;
        int key;
    };

    struct hash *hash1;
    //struct hash hash1[size]; I could do but I dont have access to size from here.

    private:
       A *elements;
       int size;
       int capacity;
};


template<class A>
Table<A>::Table(const Table &otro) {
    //function that will use the struct of array
}

template<class A>
void Table<A>::importantFunction() {
    hash1 = malloc(size);
    //struct hash hash1[size]; if I do this the scope of my struct hash1 is only whitin this function
}
```

Comment: Note that `size` must be also be a compile time constant for `hash hash1[size];` to be standard C++. You can use `std::vector` and then just resize the vector inside `importantFunction`.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except for questions about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Do not use `malloc()` in C++. If you are not allowed to use `std::vector` here, then use `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `std::vector` is not allowed, then you can use dynamic memory allocation either manually using `new` and `delete` or better would be to use [**smart pointers**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). But since you're not allowed to use `std::vector`, i suppose you're also not allowed to use smart pointers in your project.

```
template<class A>
class Table {
public:

    struct hash {
        T value;
        int key;
    };
//--------vvvvvvvv-------------->a pointer to a hash object
    hash *ptrArray = nullptr; 

    private:
       A *elements;
       int size;
       int capacity;
};

//other member functions here

template<class A>
void Table<A>::importantFunction() {
//-------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->assign to ptrArray the pointer returned from new hash[size]() 
    ptrArray = new hash[size]();
    
}
//don't forget to use delete[] in the destructor
```

Comment: youve taught me something new, this works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Olivia22 You're welcome. Since you were not allowed to use `std::vector`, i assumed that you're also not allowed to use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` etc in your project. So gave the answer using `new` which i suppose is allowed in your case. So here while using `new` just make sure that you free the resources using `delete[]` when no longer needed.